# FireFox 16px gap between DIVs problem

Tags: html, css, yui

My website renders correctly in Chrome but it shows a 16px gap, between divs, in FF.
What could be wrong here?

Link to Application: http://simateriaisportal.appspot.com 
(Conta -> Dashboard).

The code i posted before was working correctly, the problem comes when content (dashboard) is filled dynamicaly

Comment: can you provide the full HTML/CSS? I tried the code you provided: it displays in FF3 without extra space, just like on your Chrome screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use firebug to find out where the padding is coming from?

Comment: yes, but there is no extra padding. DIV height is bigger than its content heigth. i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

What you've posted here renders similarly in Chrome and Firefox.  That points to YUI Base or YUI Reset (or something else outside of this code).

Also, the Firefox render has extra space at the top & bottom of the white rows and at the top of the table itself.  So, it's not just about a div.

Comment: This code itself (as a static html) works correctly.
The problem appears when used as a dynamic content

Comment: How is anyone supposed to answer the question, if what you've posted here works correctly?

Comment: George, actually you are right. So i'll add the appspot application link to this post.

Comment: Have you made changes?  It's working now.  (Just as I noticed some crazy large height values...)

Comment: Yes i have. Its working, but i still want to do some tests in order to mark this topic as closed.

Comment: Great!  Make sure to update the post with the resolution.  I'd really like to know.  I think I was getting there when you fixed it. :)

Comment: We parsed an AJAX response and appended dynamics css and scripts to the document header and other content to a center div. it was a fairly complex solution we did while trying to make things work in IE. Now everything is gone and all content from the AJAX response is set to a center div thorugh the  innerHtml property. It still doesn't work in IE but does work in chrome, firefox and opera.

Comment: OIC.  Thanks for detailed info.  One more question: Was it showing up in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what to look for in your link, but, you div "panelDB" has a padding of 5px top and bottom, and you table inside it has a margin of 10px top and bottom... seems to be what you're talking about... remove does two and your good to go :)

Comment: It isn't an extra padding or margin problem.
There is something wrong when the content is filled (in FF).

Comment: You need to clarify exactly whats happening for us to help you! speak loosely my friend :)  How is that content filled? Ajax? Php DB Query?

Comment: He's edited the OP quiet heavily.  Some of the details are no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got it working; you should post the solution and mark it as the answer.  Maybe we can all learn something.